# Can I upload database after renaming from localhost to server?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

My previous db was dream.sql but I need to rename it with an extension  dreamtra_dream.sql. I uploaded db successfully. But didn't work correctly. It's a wordpress site.

Comment: Have you changed the siteurl and homeurl?

Comment: Maybe something like: `mysqldump -u root -p dream | mysql -u root -p dreamtra_dream`

Comment: yea, I changed @TomásCot

Answer (score 0):

open the mysql file using notepad or some editor and remove and save it.

```
create database dream;
use database dream;
```

Then create database on your server with name dreamtra_dream and then go to inside that database and export your new sql file to that database. then check the database with phpmyadmin or sql commandline then change the configurations of your wordpress site to new database.